# What Tools provide Xcode debugger to find logical errors?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I have a program that have complex logic. There are many functions in different places that change value of parameter "a".

The correct value of parameter "a" should be in range 0..10 , but sometimes it becomes greater then 80

Does XCode provide some tool where I can type expression " if (a > 10)  throws some exception" only once and find the place which changes parameter "a" to incorrect value ?

Comment: You want a *debugger*, which can "watch" a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Is `a` a property of something? If it is you could override the setter method and check the value:

```
- (void)setA:(int)newA {
    if (newA > 10) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid value");
    }
    a = newA;
}
```

You could set a breakpoint on the NSLog line and whenever an invalid value is set, it will stop there and you can inspect the call trace.

Comment: it's good approach, but what to do when there is no setter in code and assigning comes as "a = b" and not as "foo.a = b"   ?

Comment: Log after every line where you change the variable. Log the old and new values, and the method you're in.

Comment: In that case I should set Log function for hundreds times in different places. It's not convinient

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could set this up for the exception to be thrown when ever the value of `a` changed without calling this where ever you changed `a`'s value, but you can call `NSException` yourself with this:

```
if (a > 10) {
    [NSException raise:@"Invalid foo value" format:@"foo of %i is invalid", a];
}
```